# How to publish CodeNarc Reports in jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, codenarc

Currently I am using this step (in my Pipeline) to publish the CodeNarc Report:

```
publishHTML([allowMissing: true, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, keepAll: true, reportDir: 'application/Project/build/reports/codenarc', reportFiles: 'main.html', reportName: 'Codenarc', reportTitles: ''])
```

I can see the Report in my Jenkins Job, but its not pretty formatted (plain text - see image below) like the 
original CodeNarc-Report in this directory.

[image]

Is there any other way to publish the report?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: `publishHTML` and `archiveArtifacts` are what I have used previously.

Comment: Do you know why the Report of CodeNarc looks so ugly?

Comment: If you look at the console in your browser, you will most likely see a bunch of errors relating to CSP restrictions since CodeNarc has inline JavaScript, CSS, images, and other things. You can see more information about the CSP settings at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy

Comment: Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: That documentation shows how you can tune it with the `hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP` but you will have to have whatever Jenkins administration you have set that up so the service always uses it.

Comment: I tried these suggestions, but nothing worked for me. I am using the publishHTML step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161631/discussion-between-adbo-and-mkobit).